# React-native autocomplete-input onblur not working properly

Tags: react-native, input, autocomplete, onblur, onfocus

In React native autocomplete input when the onblur method is being hit the rendered list disappears. How can I solve it?

I also tried by creating creating a function of hiding the rendered list however onFocus is not working then.

I am expecting to select rendered
item on clicking over it and hiding the rendered list on clicking outside the rendered list container.